# LevelHelper / SpriteHelper / Coding Images

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have currently built my sprites in SpriteHelper and levels in LevelHelper. I have included most of my sprites in the Level but i want to also add some separately in the code. This is so i can spawn at different rates and times based on the users progress and collections of other objects.

Can someone help me or point me in the right direction on how to include a sprite from SpriteHelper (with physics) into my code. Do i need to generate the SpriteHelper code and include it in, even though i have already included the LevelHelper generated code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create lhsprite using levelehelperloader object manually at run time. see the link below http://www.gamedevhelper.com/documentation/documentation.html#top

In levelhelper documentation search for createsprite you will get enough information to create new sprite.